# Get Data From a web site and use in android app

Tags: android, networking

sorry for my bad english ,

Im learning android , and now i want to build an app that send data to a website , and get data from resault , like an app checking imei from this site:
http://www.imei.info/

that i can get an Imei from user and then send it to website , after search completed , i show result  in my app , i'm a rookie  in network area in android but in other fields like database , UI design , .... i'm good ,

can u introduce me to some guide that i can start using network in my applications , an finally can make some app like what i said ?

Comment: This is probably not exactly what you are looking for but I think its helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android

Comment: All you want to look for is [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should check [official documentation about connectivity](https://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html).

And, in the future, avoid this kind of questions because they're catalogued as non-constructive or opinion-based.